# Safari iPhone 6 will not load static website which is hosted on AWS

Tags: safari, iphone, dns, mobile-safari

Currently I am encountering an issue with loading a webpage with **Mobile Safari** on my iPhone5. The site was just deployed with AWS (Amazon Web Services) here is the link http://www.point.plumbing

The site works perfectly when using **Safari browser with my MBP**

I've done the following.

*1. Reset network settings*

*2. Cleared my browsing cache*

*3. Reset iPhone5*

I know that I'm due for a software update although I'm really not really sure if that's causing the issue.

Might be something with DNS settings?
Or it could be a AWS issue?

Comment: Is that a 5 or a 6? Your title says one, the question the other. [not that it should make any difference really]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Looks like its working fine for me on iPhone 6 : [image: iPhone 6]

Comment: thanks for looking that up. Wonder why it's not working for me on my iPhone5. I also tired it on a iPhone3Gs and I got it to work. Seems to be some issue with my phone.

Comment: @BrentWhite what are you getting while trying to load the page?